# Jolt transformation: how to shift values to each map from list

Tags: arrays, json, drop-down-menu, transformation, jolt

I have been working on jolt transformation unable to find solution

I would like to have attributeType and attributeValue to each attributeList and unique modelId and they key names should be case sensitive in expected output

**Input**

```json
[
  {
    "MODELNUMBER": "A",
    "ATTRIBUTETYPE": "Capability",
    "ATTRIBUTEID": "0001",
    "ATTRIBUTENAME": "hd",
    "ATTRIBUTEVALUE": "false",
    "RNK": 1,
    "batchNumber": 1
  },
  {
    "MODELNUMBER": "A",
    "ATTRIBUTETYPE": "Capacity",
    "ATTRIBUTEID": "0002",
    "ATTRIBUTENAME": "capa",
    "ATTRIBUTEVALUE": "100",
    "RNK": 2,
    "batchNumber": 1
  },
  {
    "MODELNUMBER": "B",
    "ATTRIBUTETYPE": "Capability",
    "ATTRIBUTEID": "cat-0002",
    "ATTRIBUTENAME": "capable",
    "ATTRIBUTEVALUE": "true",
    "RNK": 1,
    "batchNumber": 1
  }
]
```

**Expected output**

```json
[
  {
    "inventoryModelId": "A",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "attributeType": "Capability",
        "attributeId": "0001",
        "attributeName": "hd",
        "attributeValue": "false",
        "rnk": 1,
        "batchNumber": 1
      },
      {
        "attributeType": "Capacity",
        "attributeId": "0002",
        "attributeName": "capa",
        "attributeValue": "100",
        "rnk": 2,
        "batchNumber": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "inventoryModelId": "B",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "attributeType": "Capability",
        "attributeId": "cat-0002",
        "attributeName": "capable",
        "attributeValue": "true",
        "rnk": 1,
        "batchNumber": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi. What about the previous one ?

Comment: That's is also working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following transformation

```json
[
  { // group by "MODELNUMBER" values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "MODELNUMBER": "@1,MODELNUMBER.inventoryModelId",
        "ATTRIBUTETYPE": "@1,MODELNUMBER.attributes[#2].attributeType",
        "ATTRIBUTEID": "@1,MODELNUMBER.attributes[#2].attributeId",
        "ATTRIBUTENAME": "@1,MODELNUMBER.attributes[#2].attributeName",
        "ATTRIBUTEVALUE": "@1,MODELNUMBER.attributes[#2].attributeValue",
        "RNK": "@1,MODELNUMBER.attributes[#2].rnk",
        "batchNumber": "@1,MODELNUMBER.attributes[#2].&"
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "@1,inventoryModelId.&",
        "@": ""
      }
    }
  },
  { // pick only one from repeating components of the "modelId" array
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "inventoryModelId": "ONE"
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the lately generated null values
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]